# EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration : The module 'EntityFrameworkCore' could not be loaded. For more information

Tags: entity-framework-core, package-manager-console

I am using Entity Framework Core code-first migration in my ASP.NET Core Web API.

Everything was working until I restarted my system. Then I started getting this error when I try to run any command in the Package Manager Console:

> EntityFrameworkCore\Add-migration : The module 'EntityFrameworkCore'
> could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
> EntityFrameworkCore'.

It asks me to import a module, but everything is already installed and was working but suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it got solved by installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` nuget package